# How to merge two dataframes with datetime index so that the a value from one dataframe will be assigned to a whole period until no new data is given?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I would like to calculate P/E ratio from two dataframes. The first has the monthly closing prices of a stock, while the second has yearly/quarterly disclosed information about the performance.

```
Prices:
Date    
2013-01-31  36.69
2013-02-28  36.92
2013-03-28  40.78
2013-04-30  46.05
2013-05-31  42.69
2013-06-28  41.34
2013-07-31  45.48        

Performance:
Date    
2009-12-31  358525000
2010-12-31  331309000
2011-12-31  487359000
2012-12-31  488766000
2013-12-31  432859000
2014-12-31  492609000
2015-12-31  360810000
2016-12-31  735524000
```

I would like to have:

```
Date        Price  Earnings
2013-01-31  36.69  432859000
2013-02-28  36.92  432859000
2013-03-28  40.78  432859000
2013-04-30  46.05  432859000
...
```

so keep the row number of the dataframe as was in the Price dataframe, but assign the Earnings to the corresponding monthly closing prices.

Answer (score 1):

In sample "Performance" table, dates are yearly. If you do not have quarterly data, you can:

1. Extract year from both tables
2. Perform Left Join by year (e.g pandas merge https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Of course, if there are also quarterly data, you would need to do some tricks and tweaks before merging dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd
```

I created data files for the data you provided.  I had to make them the same length though.

prices.txt

```
Date,Prices
2009-12-31,36.69
2013-01-31,36.69
2013-02-28,36.92
2013-03-28,40.78
2013-04-30,46.05
2013-05-31,42.69
2013-06-28,41.34
2013-07-31,45.48
```

perform.txt

```
Date,Performance
2009-12-31,358525000
2010-12-31,331309000
2011-12-31,487359000
2012-12-31,488766000
2013-12-31,432859000
2014-12-31,492609000
2015-12-31,360810000
2016-12-31,735524000
```

and import them,

```
price = pd.read_csv('prices.txt', header=0)
per = pd.read_csv('perform.txt', header=0)
```

and then set the date as the index for each:

```
price.Date = pd.to_datetime(price['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
per.Date = pd.to_datetime(per['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')

price.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
per.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

I had to extra the 'year' from each so I can merge them properly

```
price['year']= price.index.year
per['year']= per.index.year
```

then created a new dataframe with the data you wanted

```
new=pd.merge(price, per, on='year', how='inner')
new.index=price.index
```

which yields,

```
         Prices  year  Performance
Date                                 
2009-12-31   36.69  2009    358525000
2013-01-31   36.69  2013    432859000
2013-02-28   36.92  2013    432859000
2013-03-28   40.78  2013    432859000
2013-04-30   46.05  2013    432859000
2013-05-31   42.69  2013    432859000
2013-06-28   41.34  2013    432859000
2013-07-31   45.48  2013    432859000
```

Comment: Actually, what helped was to resample() the yearly earnings values to months and use bfill() to simply take the values for every month. That way I have identical number of prices and earnings.